# How to increment the integer using PHP?

Tags: codeigniter

To increment given number by last digit wise,

Can Any one knows the solution for this question please share the answer,

**INPUT**

0001

**OUTPUT**

0002
0003
.
.
.
0010
.
.
.
0100
.
.
9999

Comment: $i++ ? Normal incrementation

Comment: @AdamKozlowski OP wants to keep the '0's too, incrementing it will just be '1, 2' etc.

Comment: try `str_pad($n + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);`